# keras ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential_61" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 20, 1024), found shape=(None, None, 20, 1024)

Tags: python, keras

```
def generator(filePath,labelList):
    for File,Label in zip(filePath,labelList):

    File = np.load(File)    
    x = tf.squeeze(File,4)
    x = tf.squeeze(x,1)
    PoolingOutput = tf.keras.layers.AveragePooling1D()(x)
    PoolingOutput = tf.squeeze(PoolingOutput)

    #x = tf.expand_dims(PoolingOutput,axis = 2)

    transformed_label = encoder.transform([Label])
        
    print(PoolingOutput.shape)
    yield PoolingOutput, transformed_label[0]



model = Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.Input(shape=(20, 1024),))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Masking(mask_value=0.))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(512))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(256,activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(len(EncoderOnlyList), activation='softmax'))
```

train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
generator,
args = (TrainFilePath,TrainLabelList),
output_types=(tf.float32, tf.int16),
output_shapes=((20, 1024),len(EncoderOnlyList)))

train_dataset = train_dataset.batch(16).prefetch(tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)

i run this code, than result is below.

### 1~3 skip
(20, 1024)
4/Unknown - 2s 421ms/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00(20, 1024)
(20, 1024)
(20, 1024)
(20, 1024)
(20, 1024)
(20, 1024)
(20, 1024)
(20, 1024)
(20, 1024)
(20, 1024)
6/Unknown - 2s 373ms/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
18
19
---> 20 model.fit(train_dataset, epochs=5, validation_data=valid_dataset)
21
22

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py in tf__test_function(iterator)
13                 try:
14                     do_return = True
---> 15                     retval_ = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(step_function), (ag__.ld(self), ag__.ld(iterator)), None, fscope)
16                 except:
17                     do_return = False

ValueError: in user code:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1557, in test_function  *
    return step_function(self, iterator)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1546, in step_function  **
    outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1535, in run_step  **
    outputs = model.test_step(data)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1499, in test_step
    y_pred = self(x, training=False)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 67, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/input_spec.py", line 264, in assert_input_compatibility
    raise ValueError(f'Input {input_index} of layer "{layer_name}" is '

ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential_61" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 20, 1024), found shape=(None, None, 20, 1024)
```

i don't know why "found shape" is None None 20 1024.

Why is there one more none?

Comment: Make sure you are not calling `train_dataset.batch` on the batched dataset again.

Comment: Thank you. I listened to what you said and looked it up and found the code I wrote incorrectly.